# Windows 10 USB invalid partition table

Tags: windows-10

Im trying to install Windows 10 64bit through USB, but im getting this error **invalid partition table**. Does it really matter? and How to fix it?

Comment: Yes, It matters. You need GPT for UEFI mode and MBR for BIOS/Legacy.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a [Linux LiveUSB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) and delete all the partitions on the drive with [Gparted](https://gparted.org/)  then delete the partition table. The partition table is what's [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) (AKA 'BIOS') or [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) (AKA UEFI). Windows 10 wants [the latter](https://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/), but wiping everything away and letting the Windows installer create partitions the way it wants to is easiest.